# How to pass props along with other arguments in functional based components of react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a function that is called upon click of a link. The link is present in a functional based component and the function being called is a seperate function. What I fail to do is pass props along with other arguments and 'e' in the function being called from onClick function.

Simply a link as follows:

```
<Link onClick={(e) => OnSearchSubmit(data,e)}>Link</Link>
```

And the function

```
const OnSearchSubmit = (props, search, e) => {
    e.preventDefault()
    console.log(search)
    props.filterProducts(search)
}

 export const searchSubmit = connect(null, { filterProducts }) 
 (OnSearchSubmit)
```

The props are coming from redux actions but this does not work. It gives the error props not defined. Is there a sequence of writing these parameters in brackets?

Comment: Your argument order seems to be wrong

Comment: Yes but I did not get any article regarding the argument order except that e should come in the end.

Comment: It doesn't matter what technology/framework you're using, this is just basic programming principles. The order of the arguments passed, should be the same as the parameter order in the called function definition. If the function expects data,props,e, then you should call it as CallFunction(data,props,e)

Comment: I think that what confuses you here, is the fact that you're using a sort-of "higher order function", to pass the event object to your CallFunction function

Comment: I called props from the CallFunction but then when i run props.filterProducts() which is in action that I have called, it gives error 'props.filterProducts()' is not defined

Comment: But you're not passing props to your function. The second argument you're passing is the event object.

Comment: I have modified the code too to show the exactly where props are coming from

Comment: Again, you're passing some "data" argument as the first argument, to OnSearchSubmit . But the first argument this function expects is "props". Assuming that "data" isn't props(i dont know), then you're passing the wrong thing.